# Java обрезание ссылок. Работа со строками

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача обрезать средствами Java строку с гипертекстовой ссылкой.

Например из строки:

```
http://academy.it.ru/courses/?COUNT_3=1000000&amp;arrFilter[CITY]=&amp;arrFilter[PROPERTY_NAPR_CATALOG]
```

или

```
http://www.academy.it.ru/courses/?COUNT_3=1000000&amp;arrFilter[CITY]=&amp;arrFilter[PROPERTY_NAPR_CATALOG]
```

нужно сделать строку вида:

```
www.academy.it.ru
```

Я думаю, что надо найти `//` и закрывающий слэш `/`. Но как реализовать это в коде для меня не понятно. Так же непонятно, как отличить одиночный слэш от двойного и от остальных слэшей в строке.

Вот то, что я реализовал:

```
String findhtext="";
try{
    XmlPullParser xpp = prepareXpp();
    if (xpp.getText().contains("http://"||"https://"))                            
       findhtext=xpp.getText().substring(indexOf("//"),indexOf("/")) ;
}
```

Но Android Studio ругается, что не может распознать метод `IndexOf`. В Java я новичок.

Что можно сделать, чтобы обрезать ссылку требуемым образом?

Comment: ну для начала попробуйте `str.indexOf` где `str`  - строка в которой вы ищите.

Comment: findhtext=xpp.getText().substring(xpp.indexOf("//"),xpp.indexOf("/")) ;  \nТоже самое. Error:(67, 66) error: cannot find symbol method indexOf(String)

Comment: `xpp.getText().indexOf` ...

Comment: findhtext=xpp.getText().indexOf("//") ;    Error:(68, 60) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Comment: ну так `indexOf` возвращает позицию, а вы видимо сразу в строку кладёте.

Comment: Ну да это немного не то. Я использовал IndexOf, чтобы найти номер символа в строке. С какого символа по какой обрезать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9608008/3212712

Comment: Я пытался сразу в переменную findhtext записать обрезанную строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > [android url get domain](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=android%20url%20get%20domain)
2. [En-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22059289/3212712):

   ```
   import java.net.*;
   import java.io.*;

   public class ParseURL {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
                          + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");

       System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol()); //http
       System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority()); //example.com:80
       System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost()); //example.com
       System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort()); //80
       System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath()); //  /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
       System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery()); //name=networking
       System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile()); ///docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking
       System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef()); //DOWNLOADING
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать. Не знал, что в Java есть средства для работы с URI.

Comment: В Java с вероятностью 99% есть средство для работы с чем-нибудь.