# Парсер реквестов

Tags: java, парсер

Считать URL ссылку с консоли, вывести на экран список всех параметров. Параметры идут после `?` и разделяются `&`.

URL содержит минимум 1 параметр.
Если присутствует параметр `obj`, то передать его значение в нужный метод `alert`.

`alert(double value)` - для чисел (дробные числа разделяются точкой).

`alert(String value)` - для строк.

```
public static void alert(double value) {
        System.out.println("double " + value);
    }

    public static void alert(String value) {
        System.out.println("String " + value);
    }
```

Comment: Вот тут можно найти руководство https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java обрезание ссылок. Работа со строками](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523860/java-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Спасибо за ответ, оф. документация помогла.

Comment: если хотите можете сами составить ответ на свой вопрос и принять его

Comment: ТС имеет ввиду не java, а Javascript:)

Comment: @Barmaley, но он же написал что документация помогла :-)

Comment: @Barmaley нет, нужно было именно на java, хотя не знаю, почему на нём

Comment: меня смутил `alert()` - на который ссылается ТС - это же чистая JS функция